# iOS Auto Layout: Screen is larger when run project on simulator

Tags: ios, user-interface, autolayout

I have a problem on storyboard.

I am using Xcode 7.3.1. I am working working on a project which migrates and implement new designs (Old project was built on iOS 6.0).

This is my screenshots.

As you see, the border view containing "Your name..." is larger than my design in Storyboard. Top orange view is larger, too.

How can I fix that? Thank you! :)[image]

Comment: How did you set constraints affecting the label?

Comment: Note that there are warnings for this layout. It is possible that if you fix the warnings this layout problem will be addressed.

Comment: Re Thomas: I fix all warnings but it stays that way :(

Comment: Re ozgur: Yeah I set constraints. Everything was ok. I created a new project, pasted this storyboard, run on simulator and it displayed as my design.
But the current project I am working on, It doesn't display as my design.

Comment: May be some cache data affecting the layout, try clean and hard-clean `command+option+shift+k`, also delete the app from device.

Comment: Re Mr.UB: I tried. But it is not working. :(
I think it is an auto layout issue.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

follow the same steps for below field.

It reflects in all view controller in middle ,same height and width